# Relation between flat and nilpotent structures on fibers?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, geometric-group-theory, nilpotent-groups

When collapsing Riemannian manifolds under suitable curvature conditions, two types of structure arise on the fibers: flat structures and nilpotent structures.  This depends on the scale at which one is looking at the manifold, as explained for example in

Cheeger, Jeff. Structure theory and convergence in Riemannian geometry. Milan J. Math.  78  (2010),  no. 1, 221–264.

Since these structures originate with the same (sequence of) manifolds, it is natural to ask if there is a relation between the (local) flat structure and nilpotent structure.  Has this been made precise in the literature?

The relation at the level of a single fiber is clear; the question is whether there might be e.g., a global object incorporating both structures so that one could study the global relationship between them.

Answer (score 3):

The $N$-structure describes collapsing on all scales while the $F$-structure deals with the smallest scale. This is worked out in the seminal paper [Cheeger, Jeff; Fukaya, Kenji; Gromov, Mikhael
Nilpotent structures and invariant metrics on collapsed manifolds.
J. Amer. Math. Soc. 5 (1992)] where the $N$-structures were introduced. The $F$-structure corresponds to the center of the $N$-structure.

The standard example is given by the two-sided (sectional) curvature collapse of the $3$-dimenensional nilmanifold: the $F$-structure is the central circle shrinking like $\varepsilon ^2$, while the other two directions shrink like $\varepsilon$, and these assumptions ensure that the curvature stays bounded in absolute value. This is worked out at the end of in Buser-Karcher's "Almost flat manifolds".